Where to add validation attributes in ASP.NET Core 8: Model or DTO?
I'm learning ASP.NET Core 8 and trying to understand the best practices for applying validation attributes to data.
I have a situation where I'm using both a model and a DTO in my project. For example:

The model represents the structure of the data in my database.

The DTO is used to transfer data between layers (e.g., controllers and services).


I'm confused about where I should add the validation attributes. Should they be added to the model, the DTO, or both?
Would it be considered bad practice to duplicate validations in both classes?
Code Example:
//Model Class

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

//DTO
public class CreateUserDto
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

So, is it necessary to duplicate the validation attributes in the CreateUserDto, even though the same validations exist in the User model?
I'm trying to follow good practices, but I'm unsure if duplicating validations across the model and DTO is the right approach.
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated

Personally I avoid using the term "model" entirely because it's so ambiguous. I use the terms "EF entity class" to refer to the classes that my DbContext works with, while "view-model" (or "form-model") to refer to ASP.NET's  [FromForm] types - and "JSON DTO" for classes representing JSON structured data.

"I'm confused about where I should add the validation attributes" - both, actually - because the kinds of validation you'll want on an incoming requiest DTO or <form> will almost always be slightyly different to the to the kinds of validation you'll have enforced at your data-layer (e.g. you can't have a password-length requirement on your   an EF entity class User because you'll be storing hashes, not raw passwords (I trust!).

To add to it: Using FluentValidation for example, you can even separate validation criteria completely from the class being validated (which is what I prefer).

Not only is model ambiguous, it often refers to the same class you'd call a DTO. An EF model is the database DTO for another layer. The API model can be the DTO itself in some cases, but not in others. As someone once wrote : remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model #API360

Where should you put validation, in the message, resource, object or data model? Everywhere. but every model needs different validation rules. The data model must ensure the data is correct no matter where it comes from. A user can easily use curl, Postman or even the F12 tools to bypass the UI and post bad  data directly to an API. You definitely need validation in the UI, so users don't waste time posting bad data. An API that creates a new customer can have fewer rules than an API used to edit that customer to add missing information. So would Address_Change and Passport_Change messages

@dai I didn't know that, thank you!

@panagiotis-kanavos
Thank you for your response, based on your explanation it seems that validation in both the entity class and the DTO can be necessary due to their different purposes.
However, if the validation attributes are exactly the same in both classes, wouldn't this duplication still be considered a bad practice?


I'm trying to follow good practices, but I'm unsure if duplicating validations across the model and DTO is the right approach.

You write that you're learning, and that's great! There's always a first time for everything, so the following is not at all meant as a criticism. You are asking about a known unknown, but when you're new to a topic, there are sometimes unknown unknowns, and I believe this may be the case here.
In software engineering and architecture, there are no singular 'good practices'. There are practices that are beneficial in a given context, and likely to be detrimental in other contexts. One example is the common use of having more than one model of data in a code base, such as is shown here.
I recently wrote a three-part article series that discusses alternatives. In short, if you have models that are sufficiently different, more than one class is warranted. In the case of the OP example, it looks as though the only difference is that the 'model' has an Id property, in which case you may instead want to consider some Identifiable<T> container.

Would it be considered bad practice to duplicate validations in both classes?

We do, as a general rule of thumb, consider duplication bad, although you may also be justified if you want to invoke the rule of three. You should also ask yourself if the duplication is only accidental, or if there's a systematic reason that the code is duplicated. If the later, that is, if you're always going to have to edit both files when rules change, you should consider addressing the duplication.
It may help, then, when you realize that validation is really a parsing problem. Once you realize that, you should also understand that validation is format-specific, and should only be applied at application boundaries. Once a particular piece of input has been validated, it should have been translated into a stronger representation that guarantees that the data is valid (see the above three-part articles series for examples).
With all that said, one begins to understand why ASP.NET's attribute-based model isn't suitable for the problem.
In the end, I'm afraid that the answer to questions such as the OP is mu, in the Pirsig/Hofstadter sense. One has to dig deeper and first examine why there are two, almost identical, classes in the first place. Maybe there shouldn't be.

Your response really gave me a lot to think about. You’re absolutely right maybe the real issue is why I have two similar classes in the first place. That could be the root cause, and I hadn’t considered it before.
As you said:
"In software engineering and architecture, there are no singular 'good practices'. There are practices that are beneficial in a given context, and likely to be detrimental in other contexts."
You convinced me to adopt this mindset when approaching software engineering problems.
I really appreciate the time you took to explain this. Thanks again!
